# C++ : upload single file with http request

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, http, libcurl

I'm using an easy library called HappyHTTP in my C++ project  (link to the lib : https://github.com/Zintinio/HappyHTTP)

I want to send a file to my nodejs server.

my javascript code is as follows :

```
    var multer  = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
    router.post('/dicomPost',upload.single('dicom'),function (req,res) {


    res.send(200);

})
```

and this is my C++ code :

```
             happyhttp::Connection conn( "127.0.0.1", 3000 );
             conn.setcallbacks( OnBegin, OnData, OnComplete, 0 );
             conn.putrequest( "POST", "/dicomPost" );
             conn.putheader( "Connection", "close" );
             conn.putheader( "Content-Length", l);
             conn.putheader( "Content-type", "multipart/form-data" );
             conn.putheader("Content-Disposition","name=dicom; filename=test.txt");
             conn.putheader( "Accept", "text/plain" );
             conn.endheaders();

             while( conn.outstanding() )
                 conn.pump();
```

from my C++ side, I can send body data but when it comes to a file ,  I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error),please can anyone  has a look at the github link above  and see why my code is not working. I don't want to use libcurl because it's large, I just want to make a post with a lightwheight library as HappyHttp.

thank you in advance.

Comment: I've not looked at the libraries examples yet, but it strikes me that you're not telling the lib which file you wish to upload. Sure,you're asking the library to tell the http client what the file is called, but I'd be surprised if the library is parsing the string that contains the filename, opening the file and then subsequently serving it up. I'd expect some more code before the while loop, right after `conn.endheaders()`, In fact upon looking, you'll need to read and buffer the file yourself, before sending the data using the `send` method. Its in the docs:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the server side, so check the server logs to see if there are any clues there. My guess would be a permissions issue on the uploads folder that is preventing your javascript from writing any files there.